# Sharepoint generic view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I often make a change in SharePoint page and it looks satisfactory to me. I have permission to make changes to my site. But when I test it on colleagues computer they sometimes cannot view the change. Can a generic view be created to view changes without creating another user login? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know if another user will be able to view something is to log in under an account with the same access as them, and it needs to be a different account to the one you make your changes with due to the publishing mechanism.

In your case, changes might not be showing up for other users due to the page being Unpublished. If you Publish the page, that might resolve it, but it means it will be available to ALL users with access to that page.

Another issue is if you have custom css/js/img files you're editing. These files can be cached by client machines and in order to flush them you need to force a cache refresh (varies depending on the browser, ctrl + R in Chrome). Alternatively, if you change the path of the custom css/js/etc. file by appending a query string that will ensure the new file is loaded correctly, but this requires the reference to that file to be updated as well which can be a bit cumbersome.

Lastly, if you store your custom css/js/img in a SharePoint library that utilizes publishing you'll run into the same problem as you would with unpublished pages. Ensure these files are checked in and published as well.

Comment: Good answer by Chad.  I'd add one little pointer to what he says, check permissions to the Style Library (as it is called in Sharepoint 2013) - users need the correct permissions to be able to read any scripts (css, .js ....) otherwise the page will not display for other users in the same way it does for you.